# What is the Jacobian of det???

Tags: matrices, manifolds, jacobian, submanifold, mapping-class-group

In some questions of submanifold, I want to use determinant as a $C^{\infty}$Map, and show that, for example, $det^{-1}\{-1\}$ is a submanifold of $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$(this may be not true). However, I don't know what (J(det)) is(the Jacobian of determinant). Could you teach me??

Comment: First off: What shape do you expect $J(\det)$ to have?

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)